# Error distance for coordinate transformation (to WGS84)

Tags: geocoding, coordinate-system

I have a dataset with mostly EPSG:31255 and wanted to convert it to WGS84.
I now had to realize that the results are up to 100m off when I plot them on a map or just enter the resulting lat lon in google maps.

Is this within the expected error margin? I use the data for geocoding. So anything > 10m is actually not acceptable

I tried it with pyproj and also with the following tool (which produces different coordinates): cs2cs.mygeodata.eu

This is a sample:

Plainstraße 1, 5020 Salzburg, Austria
input:
EPSG 31255
296772.02
-21921.52
output:
lat: 47.80971875756464
lon: 13.040617960746806

Comment: The results are 100m off after you convert them to WGS84?

Comment: Yes they are up to 100m away from where the address should be... and I trust the input dataset because it is the official source from the Austrian BEV

Comment: How exactly are you converting it to WGS84?

Comment: proj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:31255")
                            coords = proj(rowdata["RW"], rowdata["HW"], inverse=True)

Comment: I have never used pyproj to transform coordinate systems before, maybe you can try using `QGIS`or `PostGIS`they both work pretty well.

Comment: Your test point's latitude-longitude values are still relative to MGI, not WGS84. You might need to update the definition in proj for 31255 to include the +towgs84 parameters. Probably 577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I used sample code for pyproj that I found in a tutorial:

```
proj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:31255") 
coords = proj(rowdata["RW"], rowdata["HW"], inverse=True)
```

The errors disappear when I use the code the following way instead:

```
wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
proj = pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:"+rowdata["EPSG"])
coords = pyproj.transform(proj, wgs84, rowdata["RW"], rowdata["HW"]);
```

Comment: thanks for posing your findings. Please mark this as "answered"